# JsonArray to List in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, list, xamarin

So let's say I have a `JsonValue` from doing the following:

```
    private async Task<JsonValue> fetchCheeseAsync (string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (new Uri (url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync ()) {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream ()) {
                JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run (() => JsonObject.Load (stream));
                Console.WriteLine ("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString ());
                return jsonDoc;
            }
        }
    }
```

The type of the jsonDoc is `JsonArray` and it looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "cheese": [
      "American"
    ]
  },
  {
    "cheese": [
      "Asiago"
    ]
  },
  {
    "cheese": [
      "Feta",
      "Cheddar"
    ]
  },
  {
    "cheese": [
      "Goat",
      "Asiago",
      "American"
    ]
  }
]
```

That is just an example but the actual file is big.
So my end goal here is to make a list of types of cheese AND find # of times they were used.

So in this example, `American` was used twice, `Asiago` was used twice, but `Feta`, `Cheddar`, and `Goat` were used once.

How can I convert this `JsonArray` to a `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is something that can be used to grab values from a cheese array, up to you to decide what to do when the cheese data really.

```
String result = jsonString;
List<cheese> cheeseList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cheese");
        for (int n = 0; n < jsonArray1.length(); n++) {
            String cheese = jsonArray1.getString(i);
            //here you kind of do whatever you want with it
            cheese cheese = new Cheese();
            cheese.dfas = cheese;
            cheeseList.add(cheese);
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error getting cheese Info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    LogUtils.LOGI(TAG, e.toString());
}
```